# Node.JS - How to detect when a given program starts?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to detect when a program starts? Is there any built in module that has an event for this? If not, does anyone know any external libraries that provide this functionality.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about(Not a real method)

```js
process.on('start', (startEvent) => {
    // Do things with startEvent, such as checking name or pid.
})
```

Edit: I'm looking to detect a single program on my local computer starting, running code when it runs(every time it runs while my script is running), I'm also using windows 10.

Comment: Please see [On Topic Questions for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Specifically point #4: ***Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.***

Comment: Do you mean when some other program on the same computer starts?  A specific program?  Or any program?  What operating system?  And, what is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, I should've specified this in the main post and will edit it in. Yes, I'm looking to detect when a seperate program on the same computer starts. I'm looking for when a specific predefined program starts, I'm also looking to do this on Windows(10 more specifically)